# How to interpret this wierd if(dwRet &lt; bufsize) statement?

Tags: if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to compile [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea) C++ code snippet and get stuck at this piece of code which gives compiler error

```
if(dwRet &lt; BUFSIZE)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("\nThe final path is: %s\n"), Path);
}
```

I have googled similar if() syntax and and found some else results.
 Is it just misprint and me should replace ';' with comparison operator or me something missed from basic cpp tutorials?
 Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpret it as someone not knowing how to escape or unescape HTML properly. `&lt;` is HTMLese for the character `<`, and would not be valid C++ otherwise.

So the snippet should say `if (dwRet < BUFSIZE)`.